# Android RelativeLayout Selector state_pressed doesn't work

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/contacts"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_weight="0.2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_contacts"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/contacts" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_color"
    android:text="@string/button_contacts"
    android:textSize="12sp" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

and seems like:

[image]

My `contacts` Selector seems:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/contacts_over" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/contacts_selected" />
<item
     android:drawable="@drawable/contacts_default" />
</selector>
```

As you can see I have 3 images: by default, selected and pressed.

But I have a problem: **only default and `state_selected` images are work as expected, but `state_pressed` dosn't seem to work.**

I have several above mentioned `RelativeLayouts` and no one works with `state_pressed`.

Does anybody know where is my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

make sure your RelativeLayout is clickable

Comment: I've added **android:clickable="true"** to the RelativeLayout and then a click everywhere on the RelativeLayout caused the stateListener of the inner view to act!!!

Comment: It's working with `Relativelayout` containing `TextView` and `ImageView` as i need to apply selector to Rl Bg

Comment: Working Now-Hats off for you

Comment: Thanks for saving my life :)

Answer (score 6):

You could also set `android:addStatesFromChildren="true"` in your `RelativeLayout` instead of the `android:clickeable="true"`. If your children are already clickeable, focusable, etc. You shouldn't make your `RelativeLayout` clickeable or focusable.

Comment: You are right, if you have child views which have already registered Click Listeners then you need to add addStatesFromChildren="true" along with clickable="true" to get the selector working on the Parent Layout.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add to your ImageView android:clickable="true"

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should use `Button` and create selector for it instead of making custom button by creating `RelativeLayout` and putting there `ImageView` and `TextView`.
Then you can use `android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_contact_icon"`. Afterwards you can check if your selector works fine.

Comment: Well, with RelativeLayout  i can change text and do not put it into image.

Comment: @MaximShoustin Ok, very enough ;)

Answer (score 2):

hope these helps someone;

1. make sure view clickable. descendants can block click event. more info search the below attributes.

android:clickable, android:descendantFocusability, android:focusable, android:focusableInTouchMode

2. in style xml you should define item element state attributes or make sure the item with no attribute must be at the end.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true">
       <shape>
           <solid android:color="@color/lightGold"/>
           <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/lightGrey"/>
           <padding android:bottom="@dimen/padding1" android:left="@dimen/padding1" android:right="@dimen/padding1" android:top="@dimen/padding1"/>
       </shape>
   </item>
   <item>
       <shape>
           <solid android:color="@color/white_two"/>
           <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/lightGrey"/>
           <padding android:bottom="@dimen/padding1" android:left="@dimen/padding1" android:right="@dimen/padding1" android:top="@dimen/padding1"/>
       </shape>
   </item>
   ```

But this sample will not work;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/white_two"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/lightGrey"/>
        <padding android:bottom="@dimen/padding1" android:left="@dimen/padding1" android:right="@dimen/padding1" android:top="@dimen/padding1"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/lightGold"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/lightGrey"/>
        <padding android:bottom="@dimen/padding1" android:left="@dimen/padding1" android:right="@dimen/padding1" android:top="@dimen/padding1"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

or you can define state attribute for both item. So order will be not important.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white_two"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/lightGrey"/>
            <padding android:bottom="@dimen/padding1" android:left="@dimen/padding1" android:right="@dimen/padding1" android:top="@dimen/padding1"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/lightGold"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/lightGrey"/>
            <padding android:bottom="@dimen/padding1" android:left="@dimen/padding1" android:right="@dimen/padding1" android:top="@dimen/padding1"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Ref;

> During each state change, the state list is traversed top to bottom
>   and the first item that matches the current state is used—the
>   selection is not based on the "best match," but simply the first item
>   that meets the minimum criteria of the state

State List
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: Thanks for explaining how 'android:state_pressed="false"' makes order not important.