# LinearLayout onClick works, but the state does not change

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick

A Layout has the following structure:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_pack_clickable_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/card_pack_bg_selector">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/card_pack_body_frame_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/bg_card_pack_body">

                <...>

            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_pack_percentage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/bg_card_pack_body"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Content of `@drawable/card_pack_bg_selector"`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_pressed="true">
      <shape>
          <solid android:color="#536dfe" />
      </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:state_focused="true">
      <shape>
          <solid android:color="#536dfe" />
      </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

**Problem statement**

So the LinearLayout `card_pack_clickable_area` has two elements: a FrameLayout `card_pack_body_frame_layout` and a TextView `card_pack_percentage`.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the FrameLayout and the TextView as a single clickable area, that's why I've wrapped them into outer LinearLayout.

In Java code I put onClickListener on this LinearLayout. Actually I'm obtaining onClick event when I click either on the FrameLayout or on TextView.

The problem is that the LinearLayout **does not** change its state as it should do following its background (`@drawable/card_pack_bg_selector"`).

**The question**

How can I have the FrameLayout and the TextView as the united clickable area with the single background, which changes its state pressed/unpressed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42550267/5064278

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try to add `android:clickable="true"` to your outter linear layout.

If is does not work you can also try to add `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` to your outter layout again..

Good luck there

Comment: Actually, your method does not work, but it suggested an idea to me: I should've remove background attributes from inner elements (in my case the FrameLayout and the TextView). Thank you!

Comment: I am glad that it have enlighted you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546514/making-a-linearlayout-act-like-an-button), you have to make your LinearLayout clickable? Remember to google before asking ;-)

Comment: Of course I googled. The mentioned way does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I should've remove background attributes (`android:background="@color/bg_card_pack_body"`) from inner elements (in my case the FrameLayout and the TextView).

Answer (score -1):

replace this code with your old code in @drawable/card_pack_bg_selector and try i hope it's working....

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="#536dfe" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="#536dfe" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="#536dfe" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>

</selector>
```